# How to open automatically bootstrap tooltip without click

Tags: database, forms, tooltip

How is it possible to open automatically bootstrap tooltip without click.
In my case I have a form which send data to a database, the user can open with tooltip new form-fields. That works perfectly.

Now I have a new php document with the same form where a user can find trough his ID his data and get showed all in the form to edit his data.
But I want in that case, that all tooltip form fields which have already information get opened automatically, so he don't has to open them by itself and see everything he entered. Areas which have no information should keep closed.

I show you my code, just a simple part so its easier to get a quick overview. Here he can enter a date in 3 different form areas (which open via the bootstrap tooltip).

```
 <div> <a id="data1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"> 
 <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> 
 <a id="data1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"> 
 <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>

            <div id="data1">

                <label for="date1">Date:</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_date_1" id="hidden_date_1" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" class="slider-input" value="23" />
                <input id="date_2" name="date_2"  value="<?php echo $Date_1;?>">

              </div>

            <div id="data2">

                <label for="date2">Date:</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_date_2" id="hidden_date_2" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" class="slider-input" value="23" />
                <input id="date_2"   value="<?php echo $Date_2;?>">

              </div>

            <div id="data3">

                <label for="date3">Date:</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_date_3" id="hidden_date_3" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" class="slider-input" value="23" />
                <input id="date_3"   value="<?php echo $Date_3;?>">

              </div>
```

I thought maybe its possible to say sth. like. : If date_1 has a entry in database open the tooltip automatically, if not then not... the same for date_2 and date_3. But I don't find a way to express that. Do you know how to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript API of Bootstrap to display it directly.

Example to toggle it with jQuery:

```
$(selector).tooltip('show');
```

Comment: Thank you for your direction. I don't know much about that theme, so how would it actually look, I tried but doesn't work. Do I have to write: <script> $('date_1').tooltip('show')  </script> and then it shows the first tooltip just when there is an information saved in database?

Comment: You need to say jQuery which selector you need: `$('#id')` or `$('.class')` a single word will be parsed as an HTML tag (`<date_1>` in your case).

Comment: I have jQuery files included in my document. I am sorry, I don't get the way how you mean. So I write: <script> $('#Date_1').tooltip('show') </script> to get the data from the row Date_1 from the database?

Comment: Let's create a https://jsfiddle.net/ document for me and post it here. I will have a look what is the issue.

Comment: I hope I put all relevant information for you here, My document has more then 4000 lines, I hope that makes it easier for you. For now I didn't add the tooltip function. I really appreciate your help https://jsfiddle.net/Jessy123/h4mpxv09/#&togetherjs=J6HxqGI3Bg

Comment: Your tag which including the tooltip, need an own identifier, also you need first to init the tooltip. For example: `$('.tooltip').tooltip();` after this you can "talk" to is and directly show it.

Comment: I have created a fiddle for you, that works and you can learn and fork it to your source: https://jsfiddle.net/dvredo4w/

Comment: Thank you for all your work. I see your button. But maybe we understand different. I see the buttons of the tooltip, so when I click on it, it open another part of my form - lets say date_1 (there the user can put in a date) and when he clicks a second time on the tooltip it opens another input for  date_2.

Comment: Now I get the information from the database by searching for him, and then I just want that it opens automatically all text areas where he entered information before (so they are now in the database and send to the form). Wfhat I was searching for is, that when the form get from the database the information that the database has infos about lets say date_1 it open the text area automatically, if there is no information about date_1 he doesn't show the form area.

Comment: Hello, did you found a solution, please?